# X freezing when starting some games on MacBook 5.1

Tags: nvidia, games, freeze, macbook

Whenever I try to play games like "0ad" or "Widelands" or use the latest version of Firefox (release 87.0 worked fine, only later versions have the problem) X freezes. Sometimes it happens immediately, other times it takes seconds or minutes.

On the other hand, games like "Dwarf Fortress" or "Teeworlds" and the Browser Chromium don't have the issue.

System is a MacBook 5.1(late 2008) with:

(X)ubuntu 21.04

---

RAM: 3.6 GB

---

Integrated Nvidia GeForce 9400M

---

Driver: Nouveau (There is no other)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacBook_(2006%E2%80%932012)#2nd_generation:_Aluminum_Unibody

---

The freezing is GPU lockups https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/Freeze

Things that might contribute:

There are known issues with EFI/Bios emulation.

I installed Xubuntu by providing the installer a MBR/MSDOS formatted drive like shown here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MactelSupportTeam/AppleIntelInstallation

ACPI doesn't work perfectly, at least it will not wake up after suspending.

Is this just a driver problem, I can't do anything about or something else I am able to fix?